# Set width of ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a ggplot

```
   gg<-ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=price)) + geom_line() + 
     geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(ShapeType),
                    size = as.factor(PointSize), 
                   colour = PointColor)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$PointColor)) ) +
    ggtitle("trades") +
    scale_shape_identity(guide="none")
```

How do I set it's width and height?
 I am using shiny and on my UI.r I have

```
 tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Main",uiOutput("plots", height = 500, width = 800)) )#tabsetPanel
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in uiOutput("plots", height = 500, width = 800) : 
  unused arguments (height = 500, width = 800)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify what graphics device you are using. If this is for the interactive device, then that is determined in large part by your (unstated) OS.

Comment: I am using shiny so its a web app on chrome.

Comment: Then it would appear to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204735/shiny-chart-space-allocation/17209387#17209387  My search strategy on SO was `[r] [shiny] width` ... what was yours?

Comment: I should have been more specific. I am using uiOutput and i get the error above because uiOutput does not have width parameters.

Comment: We'd need to see the complete code of your application, but you need to set the width in your uiOutput code. Wherever you have a `plotOutput`, you'd just want to set the `width=` parameter to some "600px", for instance.